# GCP Console: console.log() spans multiple rows

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I am migrating my Cloud Functions to nodejs10 from nodejs8 and all my `console.log()` now spans multiple rows on GCP console instead of just 1 row.

In Nodejs8, this is how my `console.log` looks like:
[image]

Now in Nodejs10, it looks like this:
[image]

My code as such:

```
function someFunction() {
    return axios.get(url, config)
    .then((response) => response.data)
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Retrying..', err)
    })
}
```

I have attempted `console.info()` as per the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#writing_logs), but it still spans multiple rows. How do I compact this one `console.log` into one single entry/row on GCP console?

Answer (score -2):

What you are referring to is not product-related. It's a fairly common problem due to how each line is logged as a separate event. For example, if you do a quick search on the internet for "multi-line logging problem", you may be able to find a third-party solution. However, most of these solutions involve post-processing of data logs after an export of the logs are done. I don't think you will be able to alter the way the logs are displayed in the first place. If you think the export is a viable workflow, the GCP documentation for exporting is [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export).

Comment: thanks for the response. But I did not have the problem in nodejs 8. Logs are displayed in single rows and we have no issue with it. Once we migrated to nodejs 10, ie changing `engines: {node: 10}` in `package.json`, it starts to span multiple lines.

Comment: You are correct. I misinterpreted the issue since it's a common symptom in other systems. It's actually Node 10 that broke this behavior. The issue started with Node10/Firebase here[1] and an internal issue has already been created (153748705) with Google. However, this internal issue is for internal discussion only, as the problem may not be on Google's side. It might be simpler with exports, unless someone else has a workaround that I cannot see.

[1] https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/pull/665